# Automatic calculation of cells

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a Zap running on Zapier that is adding a new row/value to a Google Sheet every hour. I then want to automatically calculate the increase in value between the new row and the previous row. At the moment I have to keep dragging down the formula as new rows are added. Is there a way I can automate this process?

[image: Googel sheets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is an array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), B2:B-B1:B, ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question properly you want the same formula (relative to the cells to its left) but have it where you don't have to add the formula every hour?

Can you not just drag down the formula (using the bottom right of the cell) a couple hundred cells? The formula will stay there and replicate the cells relative).

Edit: You can click on the cell which currently has the formula (in your case cell J3). ctrl + C to copy this.
Click on the letter J (to highlight the whole column)
Ctrl + V to paste - this will then paste the formula to the whole column indefinitely.

Comment: Hello - I can but I would prefer an automated script as I intend to leave this going for some time and don't want to have to keep going on and dragging cells. I just thought there might be a simple script for this.

Comment: @gillers322 Found a solution. Edited my answer